# SP - How to get Full Url on first element in Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

I want to get FULL URL on first item from document library:

```
 using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(documentsURL))
 {
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList docsList = oWeb.Lists[nameOfDocLibrary];

        SPListItem firstDoc = docsList.Items[0];

        string docUrl = firstDoc.Url.ToString();
     }
  }
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `firstDoc["FileRef"]`to get file url and you have append current site URL before to get full url.

example :

```
string spDocUrl = spSiteUri.Scheme + "://" + spSiteUri.Host + listItem["FileRef"];
```

FileRef : Identifies a field that contains information about the server-relative URL for the specified SharePoint Foundation object.

FileLeaRef: Identifies a field that contains information about the server-relative URL for the file node that is associated with the specified SharePoint Foundation object.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300860/caml-get-an-item-by-its-url)

Comment: See my answer :)... your is verry long...

Answer (score 0):

This has solved my problem :)

```
SPFolder docFolder = oWeb.Folders[nameOfDocLibrary];

if (docFolder.Files.Count > 0)
{
   docUrl = docFolder.Files[0].Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl].ToString();
}
```